# Can mimekit save an encrypted .msg file as an unencrypted .msg file?

Tags: mimekit

I don’t want to extract anything I just want to open a .msg file which is encrypted and save it as a new file but unencrypted.

I’m aware that an encrypted mail has 1 attachment which is in fact the encrypted body of the email. So can mimekit put this part back with the headers etc to be able to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just replace the encrypted MIME part with the decrypted MIME part and then save the message back to a file.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I’ll check it out. Although I felt the headers might also need fixing and the attachment also deleted of course.

Comment: The headers won't need fixing, just set the new part as the `message.Body` and you are done (assuming, of course, that the top-level part was the one that was encrypted)

Comment: Ok. Outlook is doing the encryption so I’m hoping it’s a standard encryption.